# assign a xaml file in a frame source dynamically

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have this code in a xaml file now in a event handler code i want to assign a xaml file in a frame source dynamically

the code in xaml file is ..

```
<navigation:Frame Name="ProjectTab" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Source="/ProjectTab.xaml"/>
```

here this assignment of source  is working but how to do that in a .cs file.

ProjectTab.Sourse=???

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear "assignment of source is working" if you aren't using code in a .cs file already how are you assigning to source?  What is ProjectTab?  A Tab control doesn't have a Source property?  What data type does Source take?

Comment: In a  silverlight project .
i added a frame ,a treeview and treeviewItems .I want to assign frame source with a xaml file in a "selected" event of treeviewItem.

ProjectTab was the name of frame.

Comment: Ok I completely mis-understood your question, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the source is code using:-

```
ProjectTab.Source = new Uri("/ProjectTab.xml", UriKind.Relative);
```